# Interpreting Hurdle Model Output for Count Data in R

Tags: r, count-data

I have a model looking into the use of a social media news site within an enterprise. In particular I am examining which factors have the greatest influence on the number of replies and ratings a comment receives. I would be grateful for any help interpreting the output to my hurdle models. I have run tests, root grams and so forth to ensure the hurdle method is the most accurate. I am just not sure how to report the output.

Using the following code:

```
# The average use of they as a percentage of overall word use
summary(RatersTheyAVG <- pscl::hurdle(SUMRaters ~ AVGthey, data = dfUsers, dist = "negbin"))
```

I obtained the following results:

```
Call:
pscl::hurdle(formula = SUMRaters ~ AVGthey, data = dfUsers, dist = "negbin")

Pearson residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-0.5245 -0.4598 -0.3584 -0.1358 49.6193 

Count model coefficients (truncated negbin with log link):
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   -7.239      5.673  -1.276   0.2020    
AVGthey        1.501      0.107  14.030   <2e-16 ***
Log(theta)   -10.837      5.673  -1.910   0.0561 .  
Zero hurdle model coefficients (binomial with logit link):
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  1.40878    0.02443  57.664  < 2e-16 ***
AVGthey      0.13874    0.03147   4.408 1.04e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1 

Theta: count = 0
Number of iterations in BFGS optimization: 23 
Log-likelihood: -3.617e+04 on 5 Df
```

Which I then used as a foundation to take the exp values for using:

```
R-code: exp(cbind(Exponentiated_Odds_Ratio=coef(RatersTheyAVG), confint(RatersTheyAVG)))

Exponentiated_Odds_Ratio            2.5 %           97.5 %
count_(Intercept)   0.0007178858    1.063765e-08    48.446812
count_AVGthey       4.4854145071    3.637047e+00    5.531670
zero_(Intercept)    4.0909480423    3.899676e+00    4.291602
zero_AVGthey        1.1488266855    1.080102e+00    1.221924
```

Am I right in interpreting this as follows (AVGthey is scored from 0 to 100):

1. For each percentage increase in AVGthey, there is a 4.49 unit increase in the absolute number of ratings
2. For each percentage increase in AVGthey, there is a 0.15 unit increase in likelihood of a user having received at least one rating

Another question is what I should do with the fact that the count model intercept is not significant?

I am new to the use of count models and hurdle models in particular, so I hope that you can forgive my ignorance. Happy to provide any more info required and appreciate any time spared to help me.

Thanks in advance,
Sean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple things first: As in many other regression models, the intercept is not of interest *per se* but included to be flexible enough in the model. Whether or not it is significant is often not of interest.

As for the percentage increases in AVGthey: It is not clear what kind of variable this is. If it is in logs, then you would be on the right track but if not then an absolute change by one unit in AVGthey leads to relative changes in the response: (1) The expected number of ratings in the count part increases by a factor of 4.5. (2) The *odds* of having at least one rating increases by 15%.

Comment: Thank you for your super prompt response. I exponentiated the log values from the hurdle model using the exp(model) function, which means the exponentiated odds ratio for the count section was exp(1.501) = 4.5. Is that then a 4.5 times increase over the entire counts a user has, or a 4.5 times increase of 1 count, i.e. 4.5 counts get added?

Comment: I got that part. The question is what units AVGthey is measured in. Is it in levels or in logs?

Comment: Oh I see. The original variable is measured from 1 to 100 in the data (effectively a percentage, aggregated and averaged across all a user's comments). Does that help?

Comment: Yes, then I would treat it as in levels: So if AVGthey increases by one unit which is _one percentage point_ and not _one percent_.

Comment: Ok great, so to summarize for the count data, if AVGthey increases by one percentage point, the total number of ratings increases by 4.5 times one units (i.e 4.5 replies)?

Comment: In a situation with one percentage point more in AVGthey, the expected number of ratings is 4.5 times higher. Compare for example: exp(-7.24 + 1.5 * 11) with exp(-7.24 + 1.5 * 10). Given how large the counts are you should probably be fine with a continuous regression model, I guess.

Comment: Good work, but I believe it's not "4.5 times higher" but rather "4.5 times as high."

Comment: Yes, sorry, translated from German tippi literally.